# Is this integral convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration

Does $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(e^{y^2})}{(1+|y|^{1/4})^2}{\rm d}y$ converge ?

by wolfram $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(e^{y^2})}{(1+|y|^{1/4})^2}{\rm d}y= 0.252156....$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would expect that this integral converges because the measure of $\sin^2{(e^{x^2})}$ is almost $0$ for large $x$.

Comment: @Peter   
Let $k\in\mathbb {N}$ and $A_k$ the set of points of [k; k + 1 [ where the function $y\to sin^2 (e^{y^2})$ is greater than 1/2. The measure of Ak converges to 1/2 when k → ∞ , but  $\frac 1 { (1+ | y ​​| 1/4) 2}$ diverges, then $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2(e^{y^2})}{(1+|y|^{1/4})^2}{\rm d}y$ diverge

Comment: If this is true then the integral should diverge.

Comment: Just consider the integral from 1 instead and substitute $x=e^{y^2}$ and then the integral becomes comparable to the one of $\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x(\log x)^.75}$ which diverges at infinity

Comment: @Conrad  tthank's     Don't get me wrong, I love AI. But I don't trust them blindly and neither should you

Comment: the integral diverges not converges as wolfram claims